# Can SQL Server automatically assign a random int to an IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of around 50,000 rows. The data is removed daily and the latest data of around 50,000 rows is imported in. This is a daily procedure.

The data needs to be sorted into a randomised order in the output, so the way we did this previously in Access was to set the identity to 'random'. This displayed a random integer, so when the data was sorted via this column, it'd be jumbled up nicely.

How can I replicate this with SQL Server? I can't seem to work out how this is possible using the seed and increment functions and I am aware that assigning a random number is fine until it pulls a duplicate (however small the odds). I'd really like to avoid having to run another procedure over the top of it to 'insert' the random numbers if possible but will give in if it's the only way.

Comment: Why not just use order by newid() on your query? Then you will always get a random order. Or do you need to "randomize" the rows but be able to get the same order multiple times?

Comment: You could replace the IDENTITY column with a NEWID column to keep the same random order permanently.

Comment: you could make a table with more than enough integers in it, say 1 to 1,000,000 then do a 'select top 1 intval from intTable WHERE intval not in (select keyField From MainTable) order by newid()'  then use the query result as your new key value

Comment: Note that _random_ does not mean the values will be _unique_.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add this to the queries you want?

```
order by newid()
```

I don't see a reason to overwrite the identity for something like this.

If you like, you can use `newid()` as the default for the "identity" column rather than `identity()`.  This would give a "random" id for the purposes of sorting.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - how do you mean on the second part?

The reason this isn't added as a order by on a query, is that the view will be linked to an Excel table on the output. The user will not be executing a query in SSMS or the like and I don't know if the NEWID() function works on a view?

Comment: Additionally, "customized" random values are possible with `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` if GUIDs don't do it for you or there are demands on the range (e.g. `DECLARE @t TABLE(ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT CONVERT(BIGINT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)));`, season with modulo/add to taste).

Comment: @RazorKillBen . . . `NEWID()` works in a view, but `ORDER BY` does not.  So, you cannot really do what you want, if you insist on ordering within a view.

Comment: Weeelll, the old `SELECT TOP(2147483647) FROM t ORDER BY x` trick still works, which isn't too bad on a table with 50000 rows. (I mean, you're still not supposed to rely on the order, and the optimizer now sees through tricks like `TOP(100) PERCENT` and may see through this one in the future, but it doesn't currently do so.) Cleaner, if possible, is to have Excel call a stored procedure and use its result for the query -- I believe this works.